# How to set bool var based on if string or list contains specified value?

Tags: ansible

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. I have these Ansible tasks defined in my role:

```
- meta: end_play
  when:
   - pp_srv is not defined

- name: Debug pp_srv splitted.
  debug:
    msg: "pp_srv spilti up is {{ pp_srv.split(',') }}"

- name: Set Monitoring Host
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    cd_mon_host: "{{ groups.monitor.0 }}"
  when:
    - cd_mon_host is not defined

- name: Debug Show pp_srv
  debug:
    var: pp_srv

- name: Check Usage - Set is_cd_host to False
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    is_cd_host: False

- name: Check Usage - Set is_cd_host to True
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    is_cd_host: True
    when:
      - pp_srv | search("diags")

- name: Debug is_cd_host
  debug:
    msg: "is_cd_host is {{ is_cd_host }}"

- name: Assert if
  assert:
    that: false
```

When I run `molecule test` or run a playbook that using this role I get this output ...

```
TASK [example.diags : Debug pp_srv splitted.] ******************
ok: [cd-host-01] => {
    "msg": "pp_srv spilti up is ['all', 'agger', 'esync', 'apiconf', 'diags']"
}
ok: [cd-host-02] => {
    "msg": "pp_srv spilti up is ['apiconf']"
}
ok: [mon-host-01] => {
    "msg": "pp_srv spilti up is ['all', 'apiconf', 'diags']"
}

TASK [example.diags : Set Monitoring Host] ******************
ok: [cd-host-01]
ok: [cd-host-02]
ok: [mon-host-01]

TASK [example.diags : Debug Show pp_srv] ***********************
ok: [cd-host-01] => {
    "pp_srv": "all,agger,esync,apiconf,diags"
}
ok: [cd-host-02] => {
    "pp_srv": "apiconf"
}
ok: [mon-host-01] => {
    "pp_srv": "all,apiconf,diags"
}

TASK [example.diags : Check Usage - Set is_cd_host to False] ***
ok: [cd-host-01]
ok: [cd-host-02]
ok: [mon-host-01]

TASK [example.diags : Check Usage - Set is_cd_host to True] ****
ok: [cd-host-01]
ok: [cd-host-02]
ok: [mon-host-01]

TASK [example.diags : Debug is_cd_host] ************************
ok: [cd-host-01] => {
    "msg": "is_cd_host is True"
}
ok: [cd-host-02] => {
    "msg": "is_cd_host is True"
}
ok: [mon-host-01] => {
    "msg": "is_cd_host is True"
}
```

I had hoped that `is_cd_host` is `False` for host `cd-host-02` because it does not have the string, `diags`
in the variable `pp_srv`.

What did I do wrong?

UPDATE:

Thanks β.εηοιτ.βε

I followed your advice and I my role is working fine now.

I have this now:

```
- name: Check Usage - Set is_cd_host.
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    is_cd_host: "{{ 'diags' in pp_srv.split(',') }}"
```

Comment: Looks like an overcomplicated way to achieve it to me. Rather do: `is_cd_host: "{{ 'diags' in pp_srv.split(',') }}"`

Comment: I think I might have started out thinking that but maybe I left out the `"{{ var_name }}"`  and personally I hate ansible because of that.

Comment: Didn't get exactly what you mean there. But `{{ 'b' in 'a,b,c'.split(',') }}` and `{{ 'b' in 'a,b,c' }}` are what comes to mind seeing your requirement. with maybe a preference for the former, because `{{ 'b' in 'ab,c,d' }}` might be a false positive you want to avoid.